# Async – Orgchart Formed by Multiple Promise Based API Calls Returning Data Dependent on Each Other

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, fetch-api

I'm making an organisational chart showing the hierarchy of units in a grid-like look. A call to an API returns a JSON object containing a unit, and an array of all its children. The parent and children all have IDs along with some other misc-data. For the chart to be most performant, I'm not loading any more "rows" than what fits in the browser window. The design constraints I follow establish that the child directly below the parent should be the middle child. After all units which can fit the initial browser window are loaded, they then need to receive appropriate styling which places them in a CSS-grid.

Let's say we've got the space for **five** rows `Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 150);`

The API takes the unit-ID as the query, if you pass 0 you get the top level unit. To retrieve the first two rows (parent & children) we call `fetch('…/api/org/0')`.

Then we need to find the centre child and do a new call based on its ID

```
let centre = Math.floor(responseFromPreviousCall.children.length / 2);
fetch(`…/api/org/${responseFromPreviousCall.children[centre].id}`);
```

We now have 3 rows of data. This last step needs to be done an additional two times so we have 5 rows. Again, the number of rows which fit the initial browser window may change. I'm using 5 as an example.

After all data is received, I need to check which rows has the largest quantity of children so I can set the number of columns for the overarching CSS-grid. And then I can begin doing the necessary DOM manipulation and CSS-styling to display all the data in the grid. When doing that I feel like it would be nice to have the data produced by the above API calls in one single object.

This wouldn't be a problem if the code was *synchronous*, but fetch is **promise-based**, thus the world of **async** is introduced. I do not want to block the main thread, so I understand that async is ideal. I can't wrap my head around doing sequential API calls where data from the previous call is necessary and accessible for the next call. And if it's possible to end up with a single object containing the different "rows", which I can access when doing DOM-manipulation/styling after retrieving the necessary data.

Any suggestions/input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of situation where promises make your life much easier compared to callbacks.

The general idea would be:

- Create an `async` function which will return a single API call (ie. promisify your API call)
- Create an `async` function which will return an object holding the built object and a set of rows (`{result: {id: 0, children: [{...}, {...}], rows: [0: [{...}], 1: [{...}, {...}], 2: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}`)
- In it, `await` an API request for record `0` and use it as your "root" (or seed the first row with some past row if the grid was scrolled and you're loading more)
- Loop over however many subsequent rows you need

  - Loop over the parents in the previous row and get the children for each, attaching them to the respective parent object, and also to the corresponding row array (so you can easily get the count)

    - `await` a call to your "get one item" function
    - put the obtained item in its parent's children property (or similar), and also in the correct row array
- Return the result, which has both the object tree and an array of rows

**Notes:**

- Look into `Promise.all` as a means to request all the children in one row at the same time, or some throttled implementation of it, to do more than 1 request at a time
- If you have access to modify the API, it'd be much more efficient to add a tree endpoint that takes a depth.  Depending on the sizeof this chart, it may be more efficient to return a single, complete tree than to do dozens of requests.  Alternately your tree endpoint could take in a startLevel and endLevel and return only a section.